# Adapt a VBA code for Word and make it run from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a vba code that runs in Word.

However when I control Word from excel and run the code from excel it doesn't work.

Any idea why?

```
Sub SetTextBoxStyle()
  Dim objTextBox As Shape
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Set objDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument
  For Each objTextBox In objDoc.Shapes
  If objTextBox.TextFrame.HasText Then
  objTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceSingle
  objTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
  End If
  Next objTextBox
End Sub
```

Comment: If you are in Excel you need to make sure that you either have the reference to Word added or that you use CreateObject to create the word application.  Without either of these VBA doesn't know about the Word object model.  I'd recommend adding the reference because then you will also get word intellisense.

Comment: https://exceloffthegrid.com/controlling-word-from-excel-using-vba/#:~:text=Add%20the%20code%20to%20Excel%20VBA%20and%20amend,-Let's%20head%20back&text=In%20the%20Visual%20Basic%20Editor%20click%20Tools%20%2D%3E%20References%20select%20Microsoft,Then%20click%20OK.&text=Now%20copy%20and%20paste%20the,into%20the%20Excel%20VBA%20Editor.

Comment: I found out that it is a good practice to use the full type reference, e. g. Word.Document, Word.Shape, Excel.Workbook etc. Even if it does not necessarily improve robustness of the code it improves readability, especially in applications where you are using multiple office applications, e. g. Access, Word and Outlook or Word and Powerpoint. Regarding the specific problem I would prefer the reference to Word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an `ActiveDocument` it can be safely assumed that microsoft word is running and your document is the active one. You just need to add a `GetObject`

```vb
Sub SetTextBoxStyle()
  ' You need to change word types to object as here you are working with
  ' late binding. If you work  with early binding (i.e. by adding a reference
  ' to word, you can use Word.Shape and Word.Document etc
  Dim objTextBox As Object ' Shape
  Dim objDoc As Object ' Document
  Set objDoc = GetObject(,"Word.Application").ActiveDocument
  For Each objTextBox In objDoc.Shapes
  If objTextBox.TextFrame.HasText Then
  objTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = 0 
  'wdLineSpaceSingle is not defined in excel vba by default
  'either use its value (0), define it somewhere or add a reference to Word object model
  objTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
  End If
  Next objTextBox
End Sub
```

A lot of things can go wrong

- Word might not be running and therefore, `GetObject` raises an error.
- Your document might not be the active one.
- There might be several instances of Word running and your document is not in that particular instance.

... possibly many more

To make your code robust, you need to read more about how to work with different office applications from one of them. The link provided in the comments by @braX is a good start.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! Just got back home today, tried to execute it with no luck. No errors thrown.. This is a stripped down version of my code, maybe you can see what I did wrong? Many thanks! https://justpaste.it/5zt66

Comment: My mistake, I eliminated a portion of your code ( If objTextBox.TextFrame.HasText) and that prevented it from working! Fixed now :)